# how to build a flask api that can read data from .json file object by object

Tags: python, json

I am using below code,

```
data = []
    with open('file.json') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
```

but I have to store object by object and not line by line.

Comment: Can you share what file.json looks like? I'm not sure what you mean by 'object by object', files are always read line by line, so the recombination of objects across lines will have to be done in python after reading in the file.

Comment: [{"_id":{"$oid":"5b15789136ebfc2484fd11b0"},"name":"John","location":"Florida","salary":600.0,"specialization":"Endocrinologist"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5b1578b836ebfc2484fd11b1"},"name":"Mary","location":"Texas","salary":650.0,"specialization":"Gastrologist"},......

Comment: All the data is stored in a single line so I am unable to read by object

Comment: Then you can just load the first line right into data, see my answer. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Given that all the data is stored on a single line, just do this:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(line)
```